# Specify default error page via web.config

Tags: iis-7.5, http-error

How does one specify a single page as a fallback if specific error codes are not matched?

I have the following that matches a HTTP 500 and 404 error ..

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
    <clear />
    <error statusCode="500" path="my500errorHandler.html"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="my404errorHandler.html"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

How do I define a default page to handle a HTTP error not specifically defined such as the 500 and 404 error are in the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following [solution with Asp.Net](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/).

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect=”http://example.com/errors/Error.aspx” mode=”RemoteOnly”>
       <error redirect=”http://example.com/errors/404.aspx” statusCode=”404″ />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Other [generic solution for IIS here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors). Note that here: If you are using static html defaultResponseMode=File. If you are using dynamic page, you need to set efaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" 
  defaultPath="http://example.com/errors/Error.html">
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            path="http://example.com/errors/500.html" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```